# В dto замапить входные параметры на поля класса с другими именами

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, openapi, nestjs

Есть такой класс:

```
export class ClustersDto {
    @IsNumber()
    @Transform(value => Number(value))
    @ApiModelProperty({required: true})
    minLon: number;

    @IsNumber()
    @Transform(value => Number(value))
    @ApiModelProperty({required: true})
    minLat: number;
}
```

Он на входе в `@Query` контроллера:

```
@Get('/objects')
getClusters(@Headers('user_id') userId, @Query() data: ClustersDto): Promise<ClustersResult> {
    return this.clustersService.getClusters(userId, data.min_lon, data.minLat, data.maxLon);
}
```

Но фронт присылает параметры `min_lon` и `min_lat`. Как замапить эти параметры на поля класса с другим именем? При этом, нужно ещё, чтобы это в свагере нормально работало.

Разбить параметры и считывать отдельно как `@Query('min_lon') data: number` не предлагать, т.к. параметров может быть много.